# How implement AWS Identity and Access Management instead of Amazon Cognito

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I'm looking how  to implement use AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) instead of Amazon Cognito in one of my iPhone apps.
I have:Access key id ,Secret access key,Region.
I am try use this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html)

But is here i need put CognitoPoolID;
How i can implement it , maybe you have some examples?

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to address? Using Access Key and Secret in a production app is very dangerous and not recommended.